# DataGridView and MySQL and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, mysql, datagridview

So far I have

```
Private dt As New DataTable
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Everything is working correctly, can browse values in a table and edit them however changes are not saved to a table in MySQL database.

I tried to read about doing Updates and it looks like if DataTable is properly bound to DataGridView changes should be updated inside the MySQL automatically but can't figure out how to set it all up. Can someone provide some info or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague - more details would help - but you may want to look through these.  The TableAdapter class may help.  Its job is to connect the DataTable/DataSet to an actual database.

Saving Data Overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y2ad8t9c(v=vs.80)

TableAdapter Overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.80).aspx

(edit - fixed links)

Comment: What I am trying to do is this:
I have the table showing and can switch to a different table. So displaying table in a DataGridView is not a problem. The thing is when the individual modifies the value, inside the DataGrid how do I go about saving changes back into the MySQL Database. It is MySQL db running on Linux and NOT NorthWindDB.

Comment: `    Dim BindingSource1 = New BindingSource()
    BindingSource1.DataSource = dt

    Dim bindingNavigator1 As New BindingNavigator()
    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BindingSource1

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1`

Comment: That examples are using NorthWindDB is irrelevant. That's just another database. In your case you're using your own database.

Binding like you're doing does NOT automatically save changes to the database. That binding is only for automatic reading, once the binding completes it just has its own copy of the data. You need to use something like a TableAdapter to send changes back.

I think using a TableAdapter requires you create one using the designer (?) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sb6kb28.aspx.